# Find a number by given digit

Tags: php, algorithm

Let’s say I have a series of numbers like:

`12345678910111213141516... (until unlimited)`

Then I would like to get a number from it by given digit. For example:

- Digit 10th: **1**
- Digit 17th: **3**
- ...

I have tried to make the algorithm to do it by using PHP but it always showed me an error due to the looping that I made was out of memory size if the given digit that I gave is more than **10.000.000**. `Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted`

How do I deal with this without having to modify `memory_limit` on php.ini file?

Here are what I have tried to figure the algorithm out: I benchmark the maximum of upper limit of the loop that my local machine could handle, and I found out it's **10.000.000**, then I assumed I need to make a separate loop if the given digit/parameter is more than 10.000.000. But in the end I still got that error of out of memory size. Really grateful in advance.

```
<?php

/*
* benchmark result: 
* max digit = 10.000.000
*/

$benchmarkedDigit = 10000000;
$digit = 1000000000000; // it could be dynamically assigned, i.e. a parameter. In this case will show an error since the given digit is 10 trillion

$s = '';
if ($digit > $benchmarkedDigit) {
    $mod = fmod($digit, $benchmarkedDigit);
    $div = $digit / $benchmarkedDigit;

    for ($x = 1; $x <= $div; $x++) {
        $upperLimit = ($x * $benchmarkedDigit);

        for ($y = ($upperLimit - $benchmarkedDigit + 1); $y <= $upperLimit; $y++) {
            $s .= $y;
        }

        // so it could be:
        // 1 - 10.000.000
        // 10.000.001 - 20.000.000
        // 20.000.001 - 30.000.000
        // ...
    }

    // loop for the rest of the fmod(), if its result is not 0
    for ($i = ($upperLimit + 1); $i <= ($upperLimit + $mod); $i++) {
        $s .= $i;
    }
} else {
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $digit; $x++) {
        $s .= $x;
    }
}

echo substr($s, ($digit - 1), 1);
```

Comment: There's pattern to it. Making a string out of it is very costly memory wise. The digit `9` has a role to play. For first 9 numbers, it's all 1 to 9. For next 10 numbers, every odd position is `1` with  even positions being 0 to 9 in `10111213141516171819` and so on and so forth.

Comment: I assume this is homework, and yes, I assume the correct solution would be along the logic of @vivek_23 's answer above, with some math-magic. In practice though, I would probably just keep adding numbers to a string in a while loop until the string length exceeds the desired digit - then look that digit up with the string. That answer would work, but it probably wouldn't get a perfect mark.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes, I also noticed the pattern but I'm not really sure if it has to reaches a very numerous number then would it be using the same logic or not

Comment: @AldiUnanto Ok, I will add an answer soon.

Comment: @vivek_23 can’t wait for that

Comment: @McCartney Any update?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that there's always `10^n - 10^(n-1)` number of n-digit long numbers (even 1 digit, because I see 0 is not there).

With this knowledge, you can skip potentially huge number of numbers.
You start with n=1, and check if the number of n digit numbers is lower than the desired digit. If it is, then reduce the number of n digit numbers from the desired number, increase n by one and start again.

For example: you want to know the 512th digit in that number
Is the number of 1 digit numbers (10) lower than the desired digit (512)?
Yes, so the desired digit should be reduced by that many (512 - 9).
Is the number of 2 digit numbers (90) lower than the desired digit (503 now)?
Yes, so the desired digit should be reduced by that many (503 - 90).
Is the number of 3 digit numbers (900) lower than the desired digit(413 now)?
No, so the desired digit is one of the digits of a 3 digit number.
413 / 3 is 137 (rounded down), so it's one of the digits of the 137th 3 digit numbers (so 237).
413 % 3 (modulo) is 2, so it's the 2nd digit, so it's supposed to be 3.

There can be miscalculations in this, but the overall logic should not be far.

**Edit**: you could also use a generator, but this can increase the runtime for big numbers

```php
function getNthDigit() {
    for ($i = 0;; ++$i) { // Start with 0, which is the 0-th digit
        foreach (str_split((string)$i) as $digit) {
            yield $digit;
        }
    }
}

$desiredDigit = 512;
foreach (getNthDigit() as $number => $digit) {
    if ($number == $desiredDigit) {
        break;
    }
}
// $digit should be the desired digit
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It’s such a clean and short way to do the trick but unfortunately I got the error of PHP max execution time when the $desiredDigit is 1 billion, how do we deal with this?

Comment: There's a function called `set_time_limit()`, but I'd use that only if the script runs in CLI and we can't get the first, more complex, but supposedly faster method to work

Comment: Yea, however, I wonder if we could do this without any “cheat” such as either set memory_limit or set_time_limit for execution

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function getDigit($Nth){

    if($Nth < 10) return $Nth;

    $no_of_digits = 1;
    $current_contribution = 9;
    $actual_length = 9;
    $prev_length = 0;
    $starting_number = 1;


    $power_of_10 = 1;

    while($actual_length < $Nth){
        $no_of_digits++;
        $current_contribution *= 10;
        $prev_length = $actual_length;
        $actual_length += ($current_contribution * $no_of_digits);
        $power_of_10 *= 10;
        $starting_number *= 10;
    }

    $Nth = $Nth - $prev_length;
    $offset = $Nth % $no_of_digits === 0 ? intval($Nth / $no_of_digits) - 1 : intval($Nth / $no_of_digits);

    $number = strval($starting_number + $offset);

    for($i=1;$i<=$no_of_digits;++$i){
        if(($Nth - $i) % $no_of_digits === 0){
            return $number[$i-1];
        }
    }
}

// first 100 Digits 
for($i=1;$i<=100;++$i){
    echo getDigit($i),PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/3l0I7

**Algorithm:**

> To find the n<sup>th</sup> digit, we will first find the number and then which digit of that number to choose as an answer.

**Find the number:**

- If we carefully observe, the series increases in a sequential manner, such as shown in the table.

**Table:**

```
| Digits| Total numbers(of current digit)| Total Digits | Total digits of whole string  |
|-------|--------------------------------|--------------|-------------------------------|
| 1     | 9                              | 9            | 9                             |
| 2     | 90                             | 180          | 189                           |
| 3     | 900                            | 2700         | 2889                          |
| 4     | 9000                           | 36000        | 38889                         |
```

- The above table shows us that if we want to find, let's say 500<sup>th</sup> digit, then it's some digit of  3 digit number. If we go for 17<sup>th</sup> digit, then it's some digit of a 2 digit number and so on.
- Now, let's take **200<sup>th</sup> digit** as an example. Since it's less than `2889` and greater than `189`, it's from a **3 digit** number.
- What we would do is breakdown the `200` into a smaller number such as `200 - 189 = 11`. This `11` means that it's 11th digit of some 3 digit number which started with initial `3` digit number of `100`(the starting number for 3 digit).
- Now, we do `11 / 3`(where `3` is number of digits) and get the quotient as `3`. This `3` means that it's `3` numbers **past** the starting number `100`, which we can say as `100 + 3 = 103`(since it's 100,101,102 and then the 4th one as 103).
- Now, we came to know that the number is `103`. All is left to find out is which digit from `103`.
- **Note that** sometimes we come across a corner case of even divisibility such as 12 / 3. In this case, we subtract 1 from the quotient since our series of 3 digits starts from 100 and not 101( and so on and so forth for other digits).

**Find out the digit:**

- Now, we know that the number is `103` for a `200` th digit( a.k.a `11` as we calculated above). To find out which one, we write down numbers of 3 digits in sequence and closely observe them.

**Sequence:**

```
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 2 1  0  3  1  0  4  1  0  5  1  0  6

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

- If you observe, you can understand that the most MSB digit follows a sequence of 1,4,7,10,13 etc. Second most MSB follows a sequence of 2,5,8,11,14 etc and the last MSB(which is LSB) follows a sequence of 3,6,9,12,15 etc.
- So, from th above sequence, it's pretty evident that `11`(which we got after breaking down `200` initially) belongs to a sequence of the 2<sup>nd</sup> most MSB digit.
- So, the final answer from **103** is **0** (the 2nd digit from left).

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = '12345678910111213141516';

echo $num[16];
```

Result: **3**

Comment: then I need to write the `$num` manually until 10.000.000 or even more??

Comment: That's a completely separate problem.  Are you trying to generate a number greater than 10 million?  How are you generating it -- randomly, with parameters?  As I understood your question, something else is generating this number and you're trying to find the nth digit in that number.

Comment: Yes, generate the number randomly with (let's say) a parameter. The problem is, I have mentioned there in a question that it showed me an error about out of memory size if the parameter is more than 10 million

Comment: Then you should generate this number in chunks (of whatever, 1 million digits), saving these chunks in text files.  If you want to find the 12,000,049 digit, your code will know to look for the 49th digit in the 12th file.